# capturar fecha y hora actual en php y enviarlo a mysql

Tags: php

hola amigos tengo una duda, recien estoy entrando al mundo de la programacion en php, estoy haciento un proyecto de asistencias de trabajadores, y quiero agregar su fecha y hora de entra, y su fecha y hora de salida, lo estoy haciendo con codigo de barras, que al pasar el codigo por el lector automaticamente envie la fecha y hora actual a la base de datos en mysql, eh intentado pero no logro que se guarde la fecha y hora de entrada en la base de datos, en codigo de barras es el rfc de cada trabajador, tengo una tabla con los campos rfc, fecha_entrada, hora_entrada, quiero que al ingresar el codigo en un formulario en php automaticamente rellene los campos de fecha y hora en la base de datos.

si alguien pudiera ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho, llevo 2 dias buscando solucion pero no encuentro

Comment: Primero... no sé por qué divides fecha_entrada y hora_entrada en lugar de utilizar un datetime, pero bueno... En segundo lugar, la fecha y la hora a guardar en la base de datos la tienes que obtener en el momento de la inserción, y si quieres enviarla de vuelta a la página una vez insertado a modo de información. Pero no es la página del navegador (que contiene el formulario) la que la tiene que suministrar, porque imagínate que se ha cargado hace 20 minutos... la enviaría caducada (además de que la parte de cliente es manipulable).

Comment: No aportas el código que estás usando, y a ciegas va a ser imposible ayudarte. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio y pulsa sobre [edit] para modificar tu pregunta con los nuevos datos para recibir mejores respuestas.

Comment: define una columna como datetime y valor predeterminado la fecha/hora actual ( `DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ) y no la incluis al insertar el registro. ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Fecha actual en formato date para mysql (Ej: 2022-06-11):

```
<?=date("Y-m-d")?>
```

Hora actual (Ej: 01:51):

```
<?=date("H:i:s")?>
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

puededes hacerlo asi:

```
// define el pais donde estas
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
// toma la hora de ese pais
echo date("Y-m-d h:m");
```

referencia:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php